# download file, without saving in server

Tags: php, header

Or possible for users to download the file without saving it on the server?
I am getting data from the database, and I want to save them .doc (MS Word) file.

```php
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{   
    $file = "new_file2.doc";
    $stringData = "Text text text text...."; //This data put in new Word file
    
    $fh = fopen($file, 'w');    
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh); 
    
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-type: application/msword');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);    
    unlink($file);
    exit;
}
```

How should the code look like without this:

```php
$fh = fopen($file, 'w');    
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

and this

```php
unlink($file);
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to output headers and then the content:

```
header(...);

echo $stringData;
```

No need to play with any files.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename=\"$_fileName\"");
ob_clean();
readfile($_filePath);
```